# How to install JRE while deploying a Java Swing application?

Tags: java, swing, deployment, installation

I'm new to Java Swing & I'm a bit stumped.  The application I'm developing will be installed on systems that have not installed JRE.  Is there any way to pack JRE inside the Java Swing application and create an EXE file which installs JRE and the application?

Comment: You don't need JDK (Java development kit), only JRE (Java runtime environment).

Comment: What do you need the JDK for?

Comment: wouldn't it be great if there was some sort of package manager that downloads software from a repository and installs all of the dependencies too...

Comment: @Robert  For Java, it is called Java Web Start.  See my answer.

Comment: @Robert: check out maven. it's a good build tool for exactly the requirements you described.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can create .exe files from your Java program source using [Launch4J](http://launch4j.sourceforge.net/). This tool offers an option to set up a relative path to a Java JDK/JRE. This means you could deliver your software with the needed JDK/JRE.

But be carefull. I think you get in trouble if you offer a JDK/JRE for download due to licensing issues.

Best way is to tell the users to install JDK/JRE themselves....

Answer (score 6):

Use [deployJava.js](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/technotes/guides/jweb/deployment_advice.html#deplToolkit) to ensure a suitable minimum JRE is installed on the computer of the end user.  Then use [Java Web Start](https://stackoverflow.com/tags/java-web-start/info) to install and launch the application itself.

Both of those are:

1. Supplied by Oracle for deployment of rich client apps.
2. Designed to work on Windows, OS X & *nix.

Answer (score 1):

You have to use an installer for that. Try [NSIS](http://nsis.sourceforge.net) for instance